# Bar plot in R showing means and standard deviations of dependent variable with 3 independent variables

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am new to using R and wanted to know how to make a bar plot representing the means and standard deviations of my dependent variable which is ingestion rate and have the 3 independent variables also plotted. I had done a graph in SPSS which I've uploaded. I'm looking to do something similar in R but don't know how to code it.
[image: SPSS bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this chart which has been demonstrated using ggplot2 here: 
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

You need to use another summary function defined at another page on the same site to first generate the standard error. After this step, use geom_errorbar to add the error bars to the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but it works I guess. You might want to play around with it and make it pretty.

```
ggplot(data=yours, aes(x=Particle_type, y=Ingestion_rate, fill=Species)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(name="Species", values=c("purple", "orange")) +
    facet_wrap(~condition, nrow=2) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", position="dodge") + 
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, fun.args=list(mult=1), geom= 
    "errorbar", position=position_dodge(width=0.90), width=0.2) +
    labs(x="Particle Type", y="Average bla bla bla") + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,7)) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rooirokbokkie! If you do have any suggestions on a more elegant way to plot the data I would really appreciate your input.